# How to send POST request with custom data

Tags: python, ajax

I am trying to get the responses from server and save this response to json files.
The problem is that I cannot request custom data, even if I try to change some parameters, nothing works.

Here is my code:

```
import requests

cookies = {
    'e44cd683218d4334fdd9a0a70f77718b': '70e21e527a02d22cbd7c74f423b00666',
    'cookieconsent_status': 'allow',
    '_gcl_au': '1.1.1044858313.1660121622',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    # 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Referer': 'https://global-standard.org/find-suppliers-shops-and-inputs/certified-suppliers/database/search_results?total=9461',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Origin': 'https://global-standard.org',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    # Requests sorts cookies= alphabetically
    # 'Cookie': 'e44cd683218d4334fdd9a0a70f77718b=70e21e527a02d22cbd7c74f423b00666; cookieconsent_status=allow; _gcl_au=1.1.1044858313.1660121622',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
}

params = {
    'task': 'xforms_get_items',
    'context': 'search',
}

data = {
    'condition': '',
    'order': '',
    'limit': '10',
    'page': '0',
    'pageChanged': 'false',
}

response = requests.post('https://global-standard.org/find-suppliers-shops-and-inputs/certified-suppliers/database/search', params=params, cookies=cookies, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Let say I want to send POST request with next data

```
data = {
    'condition': '',
    'order': '',
    'limit': '50',
    'page': '3',
    'pageChanged': 'false',
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, they provided option to request all data from list!

so that my code worked

Answer (score 0):

I believe 'limit' and 'page' value is what you want to change and pass as a payload, so just give it some variables line 'a' or 'b' and pass 'a' or 'b' in place of '50' and '3' thats It.

Comment: The real problem that I see no changes when I change these variables. So that I got same response any time when I change values